# Reverse Button Background color to default color in Android SDK

Tags: android, button, sdk, colors

I am writing a program with only one button. At beginning, the button is in default color; when clicking on the button, it's background color turns to red, and then clicking once more, its background color turns to it's default color. Any suggestion on writing a code in `myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){}` method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Class member variable
private Drawable defaultDrawable;

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    if(defaultDrawable == null)
    {
        defaultDrawable = myButton.getDrawable();
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else
    {
        myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(defaultDrawable);
        defaultDrawable=null;
    }

}
```

You can definitely improve the logic to be more readable.

Also you can simply use ToggleButton, which has two states. Each state has its own background drawable/color which you can specify in xml file. No need of listener.

Comment: In fact, I am making a multiple choice quiz. Each choice is a button. I want to change the color of all buttons back to their default color when moving to next question

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply this:

```
 boolean isSelected = false;
 int color1 = R.color.mycolor1;
 int color2 = R.color.mycolor2;
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isSelected){
                  btn.setBackgroundColor( color1 );
            } else {
                btn.setBackgroundColor( color2 );
            }
            isSelected = !isSelected;               
        }
    });
```

Another solution is to extend the Button Class, storing your isSelected flag as a member class. In this way, you can reuse this kind of button wherever you need.

Comment: I just want to set back to DEFAULT color

Answer (score 0):

You can get the color from the R.attr.buttonStyle of your current theme like so:

```
  public static int getAttrResId( Context context, int attrId ) {
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute( attrId, outValue, true );
    return outValue.resourceId;
  }
```